# How to mix conditions and concatenation in [ngClass]

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular8, ng-class, property-binding

I have a div which needs to be blurred/reduced opacity on `mouseenter`.

I've created 2 css class called `.blur` and `.less-opacity`

### Component.css

```
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}

.less-opacity {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

---

I have variables in the TS to switch from blurred to non-blurred. There also are `Input()` variables and one of those is the name of a FontAwesome Icon.

### Component.ts

```
...

  @Input() iconName: string; //Contains for example 'bed'
  @Input() subTitle: string;
  @Input() info: string;
  private isVisible: boolean = true;
  private isBlurred: boolean = false;

...

  switchVisible() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    this.isBlurred = !this.isBlurred;
  }
```

---

I can't figure out how to properly code the `[ngClass]` to have both conditions for `.blur` and `.less-opacity` and at the same time a concatenation for the FontAwesome Icon name.

### Component.html

```
<div class="vignette d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" (mouseenter)="switchVisible()" (mouseleave)="switchVisible()">
    <i [ngClass]="{ 'blur' : isBlurred, 'less-opacity' : !isVisible, 'fa-' + iconName : true }" class="vignette-icon fal fa-3x"></i>
    <p [ngClass]="{ 'blur' : isBlurred, 'less-opacity' : !isVisible}" class="vignette-subtitle px-3">{{ subTitle }}</p>
    <p class="vignette-info px-3"></p>
</div>
```

As you can see i've tried with the following method 
`[ngClass]="{'my-class': expression, 'my-class2': expression }"`

I don't have console errors but the icon class isn't properly set and result with an error icon.

Here's the result I have when the `mouseenter` event is fired

[image]

The `.blur` and `.less-opacity` classes are properly added to the `<p>`, but the `<i>` isn't properly set.

My question is : **How should I code the** `[ngClass]` **for the** `<i>` **which needs concatenation in the classname ?**

Comment: Looks correct to me. Are you sure the variables contain the values you expect? Maybe output them on the page to be sure?

Comment: `IsVisible` and `IsBlurred` are private try changing them to public.

Comment: Pretty certain @JosefKatič is correct. When it is private, it is undefined in the view which equates to false.

Comment: I tried to pass the "logic" to the controller to avoid using a concatenation in the `[ngClass]`, so the 'fa-' is added in the `ngOnInit()`. I also switched `private` to `public` but the behavior of the component is still the same. The blur effect works on `mouseenter` but the `<i>` tag has weird behavior. As advised I outputted the `iconName` and it is correctly set (for example `fa-bed`). I don't understand... Would it be FontAwesome related ?

Comment: Please change your last condition to : 
"true ?  'fa-' + iconName : ''"

Comment: @Fmerco `<i [ngClass]="{ 'blur' : isBlurred, 'less-opacity' : !isVisible, true ? 'fa-' + iconName : '' }" class="vignette-icon fal fa-3x"></i>` throws an error in the console : `Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 57 in [{ 'blur' : isBlurred, 'less-opacity' : !isVisible, true ? 'fa-' + iconName : '' }] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, I had to find a workaround as long as I couldn't find any way to make it work properly with only one `[ngClass]`.

I have wrapped the `<i>` in a `span` and apply `.blurred` and `.less-opacity` to the `span`. Additionally, I have a simple `[ngClass]` for the `<i>` tag with the `iconName` set as wanted.

### Component.html

```
...
<span class="vignette-icon" [ngClass]="{ 'blur' : isBlurred, 'less-opacity' : !isVisible }">
 <i [ngClass]="'fa-3x fal ' + iconName"></i>
</span>
...
```

### Component.ts

```
...
@Input() iconName: string;

...

ngOnInit() {
 this.setIconName(this.iconName);
}

...

setIconName(iconName: string) {
 if(!iconName.includes('fa-')) {
   this.iconName = 'fa-' + iconName;
 }
}

...
```

It works fine like this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setter` to add 'fa-' manually to the `@Input()`

For example:
Add a new variable in your Component.ts

```
_iconName: string;
@Input()
set iconName(iconName: string) {
  this._iconName= 'fa-' + iconName;
}
```

Then use `_iconName` variable in your Component.html instead of `iconName`.

Comment: This is what I tried : `_iconName: string;
  @Input()
  set iconName(iconName: string) {
    this._iconName = 'fa-' + iconName;
  }` when I output the _iconName it is properly set as 'fa-bed'.

`<i [ngClass]="{ 'blur' : isBlurred, 'less-opacity' : !isVisible, _iconName : true }" class="vignette-icon fal fa-3x"></i>`

The behaviour of the `<i>` is still the same, the Icon is an error Icon and isn't blurred on `mouseenter`